# How does passing structures and parameters affect the performance of a function

Tags: c++, function, data-structures

I've clubbed all the variable members from the main function and created a few structures to make it organised and less complicated. My issue is instead of passing the particular parameters for the respective function like before, I'm now passing the entire structure with huge array sizes into each function. I want to know whether it affects performance and if so a better way to do it.

```
const int ard = 4096;
const int are = 8192;
const int ars = 64;

struct DataStructure_init {


    int main_seq[are][24];
    int main_seq2[are][24];
    int main_seq3[are][24];
    int main_lim[arc];
    int cou[ars][16];
    int gx[ars][32];
    int sx[ars][32];
    int col[ars];
    int sol[ars];
    int mix[ars];
    int max[ars];
    int hig[ars];

    int save[are];
    int list[are];
    int lis[are];
    int li;
    int mark;
    int fth[16];

    ...


};

struct DataStructure_trus {

...

};


DataStructure_trus va; 
DataStructure_init in;


int fpre   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int ftrus  (DataStructure_trus& va);
int fseries(DataStructure_trus& va);
int ftcs   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int finit  (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int fith   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int flist  (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int fope   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int fggs   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int fpow   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
int fbin   (DataStructure_trus va,DataStructure_init& in);
```

Comment: what does that mean and how do i do that ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29 also google for `gprof`

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I think the question is valid

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry, because someone thought otherwise (wasn't me, just in case).

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker hehe, i didn't want to fingerpoint ;) Was just wondering for the motivation. But I do think people shouldn't be to harsh to newcomers with a valid question, even if the question could be stated more clear.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry, if there's anything to downvote for it's not being unclear, but rather lack of the research on the OP part. But it's voted for close as "not a real question" which is absurd. Then again, the downvoter is entitled to have an opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing big structures by value definitely impacts performance severely. Though passing by reference probably makes the impact negligible.

Also, passing big structures by value can make you think of this site name.

Comment: Not a different answer, but I would phrase this as "passing big <anything> by value can impact performance but you're passing a reference which is effectively a pointer copy independent of what it's a pointer to." Of course, he's not passing the trus thing by reference, but he doesn't say what's in it ...

Comment: @smparkes, I added "by value" part to my answer to emphasize contrasting with "by reference". As for "anything", yes, sure it applies to anything, but the OP only asked about structures and I'm not sure there's anything else *big* that you can pass by value, considering arrays decay to pointers, anyway.

Comment: the trus thing contains the main values from the text files, i didn't want to pass them by reference because i didn't want the values to be modified.

Comment: @GambitKing you can pass a const ref.

Comment: A related question, will passing a structure by value be faster or slower (in theory, of course in practice you have to profile) than passing each of its members by value?

Comment: Yes, passing const ref sounds better. Especially if your trus is big enough to overflow stack.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, in theory, I think, it depends on copy constructor?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker sorry, I meant a POD struct (or a non-POD class with a copy constructor that just copied each member variable, which should behave the same)

Comment: @SethCarnegie, my guess is that copying each member would be of the same performance. POD may depend on the implementation? Knowing your level of expertise you probably do know something about it, care to shed some light? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker you seriously overestimate my level of expertise (which is nonexistant, almost everyone on SO knows way more than me). I could only guess that perhaps copying a struct would be faster because all the data that's going on the stack is packed next to each other, but that's a complete guess and I have no idea what the real answer is. That's why I asked you :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie, so we're even — you overestimated my level of expertise as well :) And you guess is probably the same or close to what I've said — I meant that implementation may choose to optimize copying the whole struct.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I guess I'll ask in [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference will, as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038411/430766) said, have little performance implications. However there are also arguments that indicate that passing the struct *not as reference* will actually [be faster](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). However, it is not clear when this will actually be true, so it will come down to profiling. Try both approaches and let a profiler run over it, or simply run the program and measure the time it takes.